# Bash Script help required

Tags: bash

I am trying to get this bash script that i found on a forum to work.

Copied it to text editor. Saved it as script.sh

chmod 700 and tried to run it.

```
rootdir="/usr/share/malware"
day=`date +%Y%m%d`

url=`echo "wget -qO - http://lists.clean-mx.com/pipermail/viruswatch/$day/thread.html |\
awk '/\[Virus/'|tail -n 1|sed 's:\": :g' |\
awk '{print \"http://lists.clean-mx.com/pipermail/viruswatch/$day/\"$3}'"|sh`

filename=`wget -qO - http://lists.clean-mx.com/pipermail/viruswatch/$day/thread.html |\
awk '/\[Virus/'|tail -n 1|sed 's:": :g' |awk '{print $3}'`

links -dump $url$filename | awk '/Up/'|grep "TR\|exe" | awk '{print $2,$8,$10,$11,$12"\n"}' > $rootdir/>$filename

dirname=`wget -qO - http://lists.clean-mx.com/pipermail/viruswatch/$day/thread.html |\
awk '/\[Virus/'|tail -n 1|sed 's:": :g' |awk '{print $3}'|sed 's:.html::g'`

rm -rf $rootdir/$dirname
mkdir $rootdir/$dirname

cd $rootdir

grep "exe$" $filename |awk '{print "wget \""$5"\""}' | sh 
ls *.exe | xargs md5 >> checksums
mv *.exe $dirname

rm -r $rootdir/*exe*
mv checksums $rootdir/$dirname
mv $filename $rootdir/$dirname
```

I get the following message..

script.sh: line 11: /usr/share/malware/: Is a directory

script.sh: line 11: links: command not found

Comment: I recommend you to use the [Ubuntu Pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) to post your code and link it. So you won't lose any character and make it more clear.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Where did you find it? And the errors speak for themselves. You do not have ``links`` installed and output is being redirected to ``$rootdir/``, which is not a file, but a directory.

Comment: @gertvdijk from offensivecomputing. I have asked for clarification there too. I should have mentioned that I am not very good in Linux. This script should help me get malware for analysis.

Comment: do you have links installed? sudo apt-get install links

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. One you do not have links installed, install it by running `sudo apt-get install links` and second on line 11 you have this:

```
[SNIP] > $rootdir/>$filename
```

This does nothing. It says to redirect it to a directory. If you want the output written to / you should instead have it say

```
[SNIP] > $rootdir/$filename
```

Comment: $rootdir/>$filename happened when i tried to format it. Checked and verified that it is showing $rootdir/$filename. the code is pasted at [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1211881/). now I am getting `script.sh: line 11: /usr/share/malware/: Is a directory
URL expected after -dump
`

Comment: Well then it appears that `$filename` does not contain any string when it gets to that line. Put in `echo $filename`'s throughout the file to try to see where it disappears, also check and make sure that that is not a typo (maybe it should be `$file` or `$name` or something).